# how to show a picture in java editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i want to show a picture in java editor when the java code contains the path of the picture
for example: String imagePath = "the_path_of_pic"
then the "the_path_of_pic" shows the picture

firstly, i want to know if it possible?
secondly, if true, how to do it?

Comment: No, this is not possible.